# TV episode about a man seeing a creature in an airplane wing trying to sabotage it, but no one believes him

Tags: story-identification, tv, episode-identification

I remember an episode of a TV show that probably aired in the fifties or sixties. The show was about a man on an airplane that kept seeing some kind of monster on the wing of the craft, and he tried to tell the other passengers about it but they all thought he was crazy. In the end we see that he was not actually crazy and the creature was breaking stuff on the plane trying to make it crash.

Anyone got any ideas about this?

Answer (score 48):

This is the classic [*Twilight Zone*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twilight_Zone_%281959_TV_series%29) episode ["Nightmare at 20,000 Feet"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightmare_at_20,000_Feet) starring a pre-*Star-Trek* William Shatner and written by noted SF/horror writer [Richard Matheson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Matheson).

Comment: They also remade this episode in the [Twilight Zone Movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086491/) (1983), starring a young(er) John Lithgow.

Comment: There is also a well-known parody of this in The Simpsons, called "Terror at 5 1/2 Feet".

Comment: On top of that, there's a further mini-parody of it in one of the Futurama scary door segments.

Comment: Want to see something /really/ scary..?  (God, I hated that scarecrow thing...)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are confused with Fallin' Hare, a Bugs Bunny cartoon?